# Why values returning null when disabled GridviewRow in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview with CheckBox and textbox in ItemTemplate.

I am using a below JavaScript code to disable a checked row in Gridview. Disable functionality is working fine but values are returning null?
***Values are returning null When i have a single row in a grid?***.

I am getting values correctly when i removed disabled property.

```
function chkDelete_OnClick(objCheckbox) {

    var objDate = document.getElementById(objCheckbox.id.replace("chkDelete", "txtDate"));
     if (objCheckbox.checked)
     {
       **objDate.disabled = true;**
     }

}
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to assist with your question. At what line of code is the error occurring? What triggers the code? You say disabling the checkboxes works. Where is that code and what does it look like?

Comment: It works fine if i commented disabled code line.

Comment: There is no error

Comment: Where do you see the null value? The null value is the "error" - sorry for confusion

Comment: after disabled , i am calling this line. var objDate = document.getElementById(objCheckbox.id.replace("chkDelete", "txtDate"));

Comment: I can only assume this means that you are not supplying the correct ID and therefore JS does not find the element and returns null from calling getElementById(). Where is the assignement for the objCheckbox variable?